# Internet connection messing my network, is it possible?

Tags: networking

I've recently had a serious internet outage and I'm trying to find out the reasons.

I have a proxy server with 2 WAN ports (different ISPs) and 1 LAN. The proxy sets WAN1 as main and WAN2 as failover.
I connect the LAN to a Switch and it's pretty much that.

The problem I had involved: 
some PCs having no access at all to the network; 
some had access to  other servers, but not the proxy; 
some had intermittent connection;
one had no problems at all;

It was solved when I unplugged my WAN1 connection and WAN2 took over.

Does this network problem make sense?  My first guess is it must be related to some software issue on my proxy server. But my question is:

Is it possible to a faulty internet connection to "mess" with a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be the proxy messing with the network, not the internet on the other end of WAN1. The proxy will control traffic going in and out of the network to the net so no random internet problem will affect internal communications because it's all separated by the proxy.

It can only be an internal networking issue, proxy or otherwise.